# jQuery load-event after replaceWith

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i'm trying to ajax load some content and then replace existing content on the page with the newly downloaded content. The problem is that I need to bind `load(handler(eventObject))` event for replaced data. I need that to trigger when all images are loaded. Here is what I have so far:

```
$("#mainContentHolder").live("load", function(){ 
   alert("images loaded!") 
});

$.get("content.htm", function(data){
    $("#mainContentHolder").replaceWith(data);
    alert("content is loaded!");
});
```

I see an alert when the content is loaded, but it happens before images are loaded and alert on images load never happens (I also tried `bind()` instead of `live()` before). 
Does anyone know a fix for that?

Comment: This content, do you mean just images, or are there other types of additional resources?

Comment: @negative read this tip also http://web.enavu.com/daily-tip/daily-tip-difference-between-document-ready-and-window-load-in-jquery/

Comment: @Orbling, yes it is more than images, but I assume that I get all of them at `.get()` postback.

Comment: @gov what tip are talking about? I don't think it's an issue here.

Comment: @negative , got it it should have some callback function like ajax which gets executed after it completes the load , please see api , and you mean need to place your code there, i will remove my answer

Comment: @gov, oncomplete ajax load handler and onload images are different handlers. Look at the code carefully, the issue is with images, not the content.

Comment: @negative , but at the end all the images are getting replaced with new content right, then what is the problem ??why do you want to execute load function on images again ??

Comment: not again, I needed to execute it only once, at the stage when the downloaded content is loaded as well as its images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may or may not be your problem, but it looks like the container you have attached your image load function to is being replaced when you load the ajax content:

```
$("#mainContentHolder").live("load", function(){ //you are attaching to current and future '#mainContentHolder' elements
   alert("images loaded!") 
});

$.get("content.htm", function(data){
    $("#mainContentHolder").replaceWith(data);  //'#mainContentHolder' element is replaced with something else
    alert("content is loaded!");
});
```

Not sure what content is coming back from your AJAX call, but if it doesn't have a `#mainContentHolder` element, there will be nothing for your image load event handler to attach to.

If that's not it, there's also this bit: (from http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

> It is possible that the load event will not be triggered if the image is loaded from the browser cache. To account for this possibility, we can use a special load event that fires immediately if the image is ready. event.special.load is [currently available as a plugin](http://github.com/peol/jquery.imgloaded/raw/master/ahpi.imgload.js).

Hopefully one of those will help you out.

Comment: With regard to cached objects, it's easier just to check for `.complete` on the object when binding the load event.

Comment: wow, so stupid of me, thanks, you are right. For some reason I assumed `replaceWidth` will replace the content of the container. I'll give it a try

Comment: If you do just want to replace content, instead of replacing the whole element, you can use `.html()` instead of `.replaceWith()`.  See the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to put the $.get into the live load function?

```
$("#mainContentHolder").live("load", function(){ 
   alert("images loaded!");
$.get("content.htm", function(data){
    $("#mainContentHolder").replaceWith(data);
    alert("content is loaded!");
});
});
```

Comment: Not in my case, because "images loaded" handler is supposed to trigger right after "content loaded" handler. Sorry if my explanation was not clear enough.

Comment: How about putting .live("load",function()... after replaceWith(data)?