# Event not get triggered after replacing with JQuery replaceWith()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replacewith

**The scenario**

I'm getting a page by JQuery ajax call, and show as a pop-up. The reason why i'm doing so is the page can be accessed without javascript also. The page itself contains some drop-down lists and buttons. In the javascript disabled version the state of the page maintained by passing the selected values to and from the server which uses php. Therefore i intended to do the same with the javascript and in such case the previous `html` elements need to be replaced with ajax response. I made an extensive search over the web, but helpless.

**The problem**

After replacing, the elements losing their event data,

> how to preserve or re-bind the events associated with them?

The code i have been trying to implement is

```
    $('#search-main a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#search-advanced').remove();
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        var res = $.get(target, function(data){
            $('body').append($(data).find('#search-advanced'));
            $('#search-advanced').addClass('row reveal-modal');
            $('#search-advanced')
            .css('top', 80)
            .css('border-radius' , '5px')
            .css('padding-left' , '0px')
            .css('padding-right' , '0px');

            $('#search-advanced input[name="select_filter"]').remove();
            $('#search-advanced .custom.dropdown').on('change', function(){
                $('#search-advanced form').trigger('submit');
            });                 

            $('#search-advanced form').on('submit', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var params = $('#search-advanced form').serialize();
                $.get(target, params, function(data){
 // This is where I'm encountering the problem
 // The first time it works fine, 
 //     but for the second time the change event not get triggered
                    $('#search-advanced form').replaceWith($(data).find('#search-advanced form'));
                    $('#search-advanced input[name="select_filter"]').remove();
                    console.log($(data).find('#search-advanced .custom.dropdown'));
                });
            });

            $('#search-advanced').append('<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>');
            $('#search-advanced').reveal({
                animation: 'fade', 
                closeOnBackgroundClick: false
            });
        });
    });
```

I'm not sure about the elegance of this approach, any suggestion to solve or different approach will be very thankful.

I already tried the following links

- [jQuery event not triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213966/jquery-event-not-triggered)
- [jQuery load-event after replaceWith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372251/jquery-load-event-after-replacewith)
- [Maintain jQuery onChange After a Replacewith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932665/maintain-jquery-onchange-after-a-replacewith)

Comment: You seem to be destroying the original `form` to which the event handler was bound. So naturally, the form element is gone, and so are the handlers. Do you really need to completely destroy the form like that? Are you replacing it with a different one, or just trying to reset it?

Comment: Why tag it PHP? Removed.

Comment: @TWickz: No, `live()` is bad. Using `.on` is right, but the delegated version may be better, depending on what is ultimately needed.

Comment: @amnotiam : live is deprecated yes. but 'bad' I am not so sure. The recommendation on the jquery site is however to use  .delegate() if you're using older versions of jquery. There have been instances where live() worked for me and on() didn't :)

Comment: @TWickz: Well maybe 'bad' is a little strong, but I'd say it's better to avoid deprecated API, as well as document-wide event delegation. The `.on` method can basically do everything `.live()` can do, including binding all handlers to `document` as `.live()` did.

Comment: @amnotiam: Oh yeah that's true. You can stop document wide event delegation by making the handler return false though. It's in the documentation. I was only suggesting live() because I have faced situations where live worked for me when on didn't.

Comment: I used `on()` instead `live()` `delegate()` because of the deprecation notice of documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're destroying the original form in the first place. If you just need to reset it, there are probably better ways.

But given that you are destroying the form, and therefore its handlers, you could bind the handler to the `#search-advanced` element, and use the event delegation signature of `.on`.

```
  // v--event is bound here          v--and will trigger on the form element
$('#search-advanced').on('submit', "form", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var params = $('#search-advanced form').serialize();
    $.get(target, params, function(data){
        $('#search-advanced form').replaceWith($(data).find('#search-advanced form'));
        $('#search-advanced input[name="select_filter"]').remove();
        console.log($(data).find('#search-advanced .custom.dropdown'));
    });
});
```

Comment: actually what i'm doing is, by changing the drop-down item submitting the form, then the view(previous form) is being rendered with additional data appropriate to the request. The form is not necessarily need to be destroyed if i succeeded in find a way to replace only the new data. Could you pls suggest me a proper way to reset the form. I know that `replaceWith()` destroys the handlers, that is why i asked how to re-bind? anyway i'll try this, and thanks.

Comment: @thujeevan: Give it a try, and let me know. With respect to setting the input elements to the new data, it would just be a matter of selecting each individual element, and updating it with `.val()`.

Comment: I solved the problem by using `$('#search-advanced form').html($(data).find('#search-advanced form').html());` since this not destroying the form and handlers, and `$('#search-advanced').on('change', '.custom.dropdown' ,function(){}`. Thanks your code did help me in another place.

Answer (score 1):

Try binding the event like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#search-main a', function(ev){
    // your code
});
```

Comment: sorry, try to understand my question.. anyhow i'll try. thanks