# When using JQuery replaceWith() function, events won't work afterward?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a button within some html that calls an ajax request which then replaces the aforementioned html and button with the .replaceWith() JQuery function.  After this 'replacing' happens the button will no longer work.  The event code is completely separate from the html, so I don't see why it won't still enact the event as many times as I need.

Here is the JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button.hit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var thisPlayer = this.id;
        $.post('/home/GetHitHold/', { action: "hit", playerName: this.id },
            function (returnedData) {
                $('div[id~="' + thisPlayer + '"]').replaceWith(returnedData);
            }).fail(function () {
                addTableRow("error");
            });
    });
});
```

Here's the html that is returned from the ajax request which is what is doing the replacing.

```
<div id="@Model.PlayerName" class="col-md-3" style="display: inline-block; margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;">
    <div class="card border-warning" style="background-color:#1C5619">
        <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title text-center text-warning">Player: @Model.PlayerName</h4>
            <h1 class="card-text text-center text-lg-center text-warning">@Model.DisplayHand()</h1>
            <div>
                <button id="@Model.PlayerName" class="hit greenButtons btn btn-warning">Hit</button>
                <button id="@Model.PlayerName" class="hold greenButtons btn btn-warning">Hold</button>
            </div>
            <p class="card-text text-right">
                <small class="text-warning text-center text-warning" style="margin: 10px;">Hand Value: @Model.ParticipantsHighestHand()</small>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So my goal is to be able to replace the html and still have a working 'click' event for the button within that replaced html.

(I'm doing this within ASP.NET Core MVC, though that shouldn't matter)

Answer (score 0):

As I was writing this I found one that worked by a fluke chance.  In the following link at the bottom by the commenter "davids":

[Event not get triggered after replacing with JQuery replaceWith()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828018/event-not-get-triggered-after-replacing-with-jquery-replacewith)

He states the following:

> Try binding the event like this:

```
> $(document).on('click', '#search-main a', function(ev){
>     // your code });
```